# OpenMax android

Tags: android, media-player, openmax

There is example in NDK latest releases calling native-media. There are two examples of video rendering by standard android media player and using native lib of OpenMax AL . From Android API14 , is referenced that android automatically uses hardware acceleration. Does it mean that in core,media player uses openMax technology to decode video?

Thanks in advance .